# Windows doesn't recognize Docker command

Tags: docker

I already installed Docker for windows. when I type `docker --version` command in Command prompt, it doesn't recognize it at all.

The message will be this:

```
'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image: docker --version command in cmd]

Did I miss something ?

Comment: This is how I solved the problem. I don't have have Windows 10 64-bit: Pro, Enterprise, or Education (Build 15063 or later) I am not able to install Docker desktop, I have to install docker toolbox (https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases). After that I followed step 2 and three from this link : https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/ ) [Latest Docker Toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CRrA.png)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I restarted the system, it worked, maybe we can say that a restart is required.

Comment: Thanks so much! I recently used Chocolatey to re-install Docker for Windows and was baffled like "I don't remember adding the path in PowerShell the first time I installed."  Alas, I simply needed to restart :)

Comment: Why is a restart required?

Comment: Cool, that was it!

Answer (score 94):

I had installed Docker 18.06.1-ce version on my Windows 10 machine and faced the similar issue, even though the docker was added the Windows %PATH%.

I moved the docker path to the bottom and that solved my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: for latest version we also need to add this `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources`

Comment: After trying every other solution, adding `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources` as @deadshot suggests worked for me

Comment: If put the path in environment to fix ```docker``` command, than you need to additionally do: ```Set-Alias -Name docker -Value DockerCli```

Answer (score 18):

You need to **start** the docker first if you have not and then open **powershell**.

In the powershell, try to run docker commands.

Comment: I want to use bash not powershell

Answer (score 11):

I installed docker Docker version 19.03.13 build 4484c46d9d, in Windows 10 pro 1903.
I was facing the same issue, then I just renamed 'com.docker.cli' to 'docker' and set the environment variable to 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin'

Problem Resolved.

Refer the image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZwx4udOzJeITV2RDGQKlsOt_TF4Wq2N/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpW2DR2n_jCGezwrXuhNtXpSTBWmEDJk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please mention which environmental variable the user needs to set (Path in this case).

Comment: 'docker' varibale name.
refer 1st image.

Comment: It is the Path environment variable that needs to be updated and the executable of your docker should be appended there

Answer (score 9):

```
docker: command not found
```

Windows 7: Just set the path of docker in **system variable**

**Step:1**
[Click on path -> edit-> paste the docker location]

[image]

**Step:2** [Paste the docker location]
**In my case C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox**.

[image]

now check **$ docker version**

Answer (score 9):

Renaming 'com.docker.cli' to 'docker' helped me finally get windows powershell and cmd terminals to recognize the docker command.

Comment: how did you know to do that? and as far as i can see it doesn't exist in the current version

Answer (score 7):

Add docker to `PATH` variable & `refreshenv` to keep using the same command prompt

---

If you've installed using docker toolbox the install path `"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"`

Manually using Environmental Variable > Path (add docker path here)

---

Using Command Line

For temporary use `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox`

- Make sure to take a back up of `PATH` by `echo %PATH%` before doing this

For permanent change `setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the docker.exe path (C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin) is added to the PATH variable.

You can check it as follows:

```
ECHO %PATH%
```

The docker path had to be appended at the end of the PATH in my case. After that docker cmd was recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Run as administrator worked for me, both powershell and bash on windows. I did not need to restart.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are facing docker issue on VS Code

I was trying on **VS Code** Terminal after installation. Restarted and was still facing issue.

[image]

Then I tried with fresh terminal of **Command Prompt** --  it worked!

[image]

After that it also working fine on vs code.

In **VS Code** - close all terminals and **open fresh terminal**
and try test command:

`docker --version`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

2022 - Windows 11

Add these paths to the PATH variable.

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin

C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin
```

Docker PATH variable Windows 11:
[image: Docker PATH variable Windows 11]

Answer (score 2):

I checked environment variables and noticed that docker path is as the following path in which "R" in resources uppercase. I fixed the case and everything worked as expected
Path: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin"

Answer (score 2):

Just Restart the system, it is always good practice to restart the system when you install or uninstall any application. Hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the system after installation. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install GIT bash and then run this command on it for Windows:

```
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin" &&
curl -L $base/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe > "$HOME/bin/docker-machine.exe" &&
chmod +x "$HOME/bin/docker-machine.exe"
```

[Click Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxbLg.png)

there is some issues with PowerShell or new version of docker due to which I was facing the same issue but then I went to this [page](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) and got way to run it.

> PS: GIT bash is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Docker Toolbox in your windows, go and add the environment variable.

```
PATH = "location of folder that contains docker-machine"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also face a problem with the installation and running docker.  I'm not sure you how did you install docker. I tried this way. I've downloaded the docker toolbox (https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases) which comes up with docker,docker-machine. Oracle Virtual box which is pretty much enough to start docker locally.Please make sure you have git bash installed in your local. Once the toolbox installation is done click the icon generated on the desktop . Make sure this icon target to your  Git bash.exe (you can verify this by right click on icon and find target). and verify docker version

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to ensure the check box **Enable Hyper-V Windows Features** is checked as I was installing.

I just wanted to have client installed, without the engine. So earlier, as I was installing, I unchecked that option. And after successful installation, I get the error - windows does not recognize docker.

But now that reinstalled with the checkbox checked, things are working fine now.

[image: Enable Hyper-V Windows Features]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that running docker commands before startup causes this issue, but ensuring that docker is running and executing the commands after, they are then recognised. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I facing the same issue when I try to run `docker -v` in Vscode Terminal after install it. I try to use cmd and git bash it work fine. Restart your vscode will solve it

Answer (score 1):

just add this path in your "Path" inside env variables inside windows

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin

then restart your gitbash or cmd or ...

everything goes well after that !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, After many tries and restarts, I uninstalled docker and Re-installed it again, and I had to build all things again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, them I tried in Powershell which works someHo

Answer (score 0):

1. Download "docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe" from: https://github.com/docker/machine/releases
2. Rename "docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe" to "docker-machine.exe".
3. Copy "docker-machine.exe" to path `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*just add in your environmental Path this syntax if you did like (install docker in c drive) me, most probably it would work, for me, this passed well.
(note: if you going to `call RefreshEnv.cmd` or `RefreshEnv`
through your CMC with [**Chocolatey**](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2892), this path would not be created for you, and you have to do it manualy in Windows 10 operating system).

> `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I switched to the windows command prompt instead of the VScode terminal.

Comment: Why would this solve the problem? If it has to do with Windows command prompt PATHing vs WSL, please add that detail.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why it worked or how it worked. I just know it worked. I'll appreciate it if anyone is able to edit the answer to include possible reasons.