# 'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to build docker images with Jenkins java application, but I  getting the following error while after starting the job in Jenkins..

Commands used in Build Step inside Jenkins:

```
cd JenkinsWithSonar_SB
mvn clean install
docker build -f Dockerfile -t springboot-sonar-docker .
```

The error message is:

> 'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Don't you need a separator ; between these commands?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the path to docker in the jenkins enviroment. It reads like windows - see this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478343/windows-doesnt-recognize-docker-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows doesn't recognize Docker command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478343/windows-doesnt-recognize-docker-command)