# Path to docker with python and subprocess

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I would like to use pdf2htmlex with a Python script. Therefore, I installed Docker on my Windows machine. I was able to convert a PDF using the following command in PowerShell:

```
docker run -ti --rm --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/pdf,type=bind pdf2htmlex/pdf2htmlex:0.18.8.rc2-master-20200820-ubuntu-20.04-x86_64 --zoom 1.3 test3.pdf
```

In VSCode, I created the following function to change the directory and select the PDF to convert:

```
def pdf2html(path, filename):
import subprocess
text = "docker run -ti --rm --mount src=" + path + ",target=/pdf,type=bind pdf2htmlex/pdf2htmlex:0.18.8.rc2-master-20200820-ubuntu-20.04-x86_64 --zoom 1.3"
subprocess.call(text + filename, shell = False)
pdf2html("C:/Users/1/", "test4.pdf")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

*FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvabletext*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you should use `shell=True`

Comment: This is almost a poster example of a _shell injection attack_: if I can set `path` to `/,target=/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow;` then I can get a file of encrypted passwords to crack offline, for example, or do other things to more directly compromise the host system.  Given the security implications of trying to directly launch a Docker container, do you really need Docker here, or can you run this converter as an ordinary non-container subprocess?

Comment: @AhmedAEK shell=True returns : 'docker' is not recognized as an internal command

Comment: @DavidMaze Can I and would it be safier to send the document within the docker? If so, how can I do it? Sorry for the naive questions its my first day using docker.

Comment: you should find a fix for that (broken environment variables, specifically PATH) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478343/windows-doesnt-recognize-docker-command , anyway as DavidMaze suggests not to launch docker within your app, it would be better (for more than just security) to have the docker container up and running all the time as a server and your program connecting to it at runtime using a socket, exposing only the necessary interfaces to the outside world .... and you won't need to change the environment variables.

Comment: if it works within powershell then you could just add `powershell docker ...` at the start of the command ... it will work without any changes to environment variables.